# The published artifacts cannot be deleted in vNext build definition in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, build, vnext

I am working on vNext build in TFS Version 15.117.27414.0. 
I published the build artifacts to a shared file path.
After I deleted the build record in history tab manually, why the drop folder of artifacts still exists in shared folder?

[Retention settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUmvW.png)

[The message when I delete the build history record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCHxd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Tested on my side with TFS 2017 Update3 (`TFS Version 15.117.27414.0`) and the `drop` folder can be deleted successfully from the shared network path.

However the `Parent` folder (the Folder above the Drop folder) of the artifacts will not be deleted, it just delete the drop folder and it's contents.

If that still not work, just try to create a new build definition and try it again.

[image]

Comment: Ok, i am trying to create another build and try again.

Comment: BTW, do you know how the build system detect the drop folder path when i delete the build record?

Comment: @zgu It should be set in Retention policies

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I think my retention policy seems is correct.

Comment: @zgu Yeah, the `File Share` need to be selected in the retention policy. So can you reproduce the issue with the new builds? I mean create a new build definition and queue new builds, then check that again.