# How do I delete the artifacts published by my build pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline, build-pipeline

I have a security issue with the artifacts in my build pipeline.

**How do I delete the artifacts without deleting the entire pipeline?**

Unlike the answers to the related posts below, I do not want to change the retention policy on the Azure DevOps project. The project contains repos I don't have control over.

Related posts:

1. [The published artifacts cannot be deleted in vNext build definition in TFS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51037259/the-published-artifacts-cannot-be-deleted-in-vnext-build-definition-in-tfs-2017)
2. [How to delete Azure pipeline artifacts after it's finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251420/how-to-delete-azure-pipeline-artifacts-after-its-finished)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **How do I delete the artifacts without deleting the entire pipeline?**

### Solution

- [Deleting the offending test runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/retention?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#delete-a-run) also deleted the artifacts. :-)
- Some users may also have to [delete the retention policy on the run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/multi-stage-pipelines-experience?view=azure-devops#view-pipeline-run-details).